# Get Whole number part of a float :Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c

So i have

float x = x + 0.25;

This float will be called every time a click happens

NSLog(@"%f",x);

I want the nslog to only return the whole number portion so like this

```
  x        return
```

---

```
 1.25         1
 1.50         1
 3.25         3
 4.75         4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Converting to `int` won't work if the floating-point number is outside the range of `int`.

Printing with `"%.0f"` doesn't truncate, it rounds, so 4.75 will print as `5`.

If your compiler (more accurately, your runtime library) supports them, the `trunc()`, `truncf()`, and `truncl()` functions, declared in `<math.h>`, do exactly what you want:

```
printf("%.0f\n", trunc(x));
```

Those functions are new in C99, so it's possible your compiler doesn't support them.  C90 does provide a `floor()` function; you can use that if you write some special-case code for negative numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can treat x as an int (cast):

```
NSLog("%d", (int)x);
```

Note: this will not round, it will truncate the value, returning only the integer part.

EDIT: please note that this is not a safe way to truncate all possible float values, it will work fine for small values though (those fitting in an `int`).

Comment: But it will fail if x is outside the range `INT_MIN` .. `INT_MAX`.

Comment: If you prefer, you can use long long, or unsigned as needed to increase the available range.

Comment: On every implementation I've heard of, the largest integer type is too narrow to hold the full range of the narrowest floating-point type.  And there's `trunc()`.

Comment: Ok for precision. I was aiming for simplicity, but I'll edit my answer.